# How playstore detects our app contains ads or not?

Tags: android, google-play-services, ads

My Question was stated in title.
I have seen ads in Quora app but on Install screen play store doesn't show it contains ads? How did they do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Quora application have their own ad module which they show in their application. They don't use AdMob or any other Ad sdk's.

And about google, i was updating my android application once on playstore which earlier have ads in it but due to some reason i removed ads from my application but i don't remove the dependency from the `build gradle` and as soon as i clicked on publish a pop-up appears "Are you sure this application doesn't contains ads, as their is module present in the application.". Also their was link to the google ad policy just to remind the developer about the policies.

So, according to me google checks the `build gradle` files of your application.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for the info. Out of curiosity, Suppose if we are using some kind of adservice which are not well known and can't be detected by google, then can we use it and select "there are no ads" in my app to publish app?

Comment: I guess not well known adservice will not be that flexible to use, and yes you can use that there are no ads in my app. But make sure that you read all the policies of google play because one of my app got suspended due to voilation of policies.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore since Google changed [their policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?p=ads&rd=1#ads). It doesn't matter whether it's their own ad module, AdMob or a not well known ad service, Google will manually set the "Contains ads" badge and misrepresenting it is a policy violation.